# Drupal 8 reorder/rearrange 'manage fields' for cms display

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I need to reorder fields in Drupal 8. Ive tried installing some modules with no effect. It should be an easy task and i will not go and change something in the database.

Here is the path:
Home > Administration > Structure > Content types > Article

Its only possible reordering 'Manage Display' for the frontend view. I need the fields reordered for adding/changing content.
Atm i have some fields like title underneath body and stuff. Its killing me;-D

Help this poor man, please :-)

Comment: I believe it's off-topic for StackOverflow as it's not about programming, but about Drupal administration. Consider moving to [Drupal-specific](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in the "manage form display" tab, right next to the manage display tab:

[image]

Comment: So when the user adds content, the fields are set as i want to

Comment: Not possible as far as I know